# How to filter a row in a csv file based on multiple indexes?

Tags: python, list, indexing, filter

I have a file which looks like this:

```
#This is TEST-data
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,London,Manchester,London,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,London,London,Manchester,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,London,London,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,London,London1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,3,Madrid,Sevila,Sevilla,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,3,Madrid,Sevilla,Madrid,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-40,2,Madrid,Barcelona,1,1,1,1
```

`Index[2]` in each row shows how much cities are present in that specific row. So the first row has value 3 for index[2], which are `London, Manchester, London.`

I am trying to do the following:

For every row I need to check if any of row [3] + the cities mentioned after it (based on the number of cities) are present in `cities_to_filter.`

This is my current code:

```
path = r'c:\data\ELK\Desktop\test_data_countries.txt'

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']

def filter_row(row):
    # amount_of_cities = row[2]    
    condition_1 = any(city in row for city in cities_to_filter)
    
    return condition_1

with open (path, 'r') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(output_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

The code I have works okay for this dataset but its quiet risky as its looking at every column, even the ones which I know aren't cities. I need my code to check only the columns which are cities based on the amount of cities each row contains.

Comment: This looks quiet interesting. You could create a new list of cities as a part of `cities_to_filter`, using `amount_of cities`. Then you use that list for comparison with your `cities_to_filter`

Comment: @NorthAfrican Thats harder said then done.. I dont want to change to much in my current code. I feel im really close.

Comment: @mhawke What do you exactly mean?

Comment: @mhawke No problem mate, maybe you can still help me. Feel I'm really close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cities "list" always starts at the same offset and the length is known from `row[2]`. So just slice it out and use your `any()` expression to check for cites to filter, or you could use set operations, but that's probably overkill for this:

```
import csv

path = r'c:\data\ELK\Desktop\test_data_countries.txt'

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']

def filter_row(row):
    count = int(row[2])
    cities = row[3:3+count]
    return any(city in cities for city in cities_to_filter)

with open (path, 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

Also, renamed `output_file` to `input_file` as the file is being read, not written.

Output

```
['2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00', 'ID-10', '3', 'London', 'Manchester', 'London', '1', '1', '1']
['2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00', 'ID-10', '3', 'London', 'London', 'Manchester', '1', '1']
['2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00', 'ID-30', '3', 'Madrid', 'Sevila', 'Sevilla', '1', '1', '1']
['2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00', 'ID-30', '3', 'Madrid', 'Sevilla', 'Madrid', '1']
```

Comment: looks quiet proper. What is `row[3:3+count]` exactly doing?

Comment: `row` is a list of the fields from the CSV file. `row[3:3+count]` is a slice from that list. The slice starts at index 3 and goes until index `3+count`, e.g. for the first line `row[2]` is 3 so the slice is `row[3:6]` which is the sublist `['London', 'Manchester', 'London']` which are the cities in the first row. Look up list slicing in the Python docs (other references are available).

Comment: is there is a posiblity we can private chat with each other?

Comment: @TangerCity: probably not... about what?  If you have other questions then you can create a new post. This question was well written and contained the information required to provide an answer. so you would likely get a good response.

Comment: Well it has everything to do with this question actually. What if `row[2]` sometimes contains an different value like `XXX`. I tried this on a bigger dataset and received the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'XXX'`. So actually I need to build an extra pre-condition which is saying `row[2]` must be a number.

Comment: @TangerCity: you could use `row[2].isdigit()` to determine whether it's a number, or catch the exception and handle it. If it is not a number you could choose to abort the program, dump the row to stderr, or attempt to process the row using `cities = row[3:]` which will slice all items in the list from index 3 to the end of the list.

Comment: You could also have a misunderstanding about the data you are processing. Is the row legitimate? Are your assumptions about the data format correct?

Comment: Yes untill now they are correct. So I made this `count  = int(row[2].isdigit())` from this `count = int(row[2])`. Thats all I changed I ran the code again but still got the same problem

Comment: `isdigit()` returns a boolean so `count` would end up either 1 or 0. You should write it as `if row[2].isdigit(): count = int(row[2]); else: # handle error`. Perhaps exception handling would be better in case there are other unforeseen issues, e.g. what if the row contains less than 4 items?

Comment: yeah thats quiete an issue. Let me ask a new question. I'l tagg you in it.